# Initialize a character array from a constexpr string

Tags: c++, constexpr

I had code similar to this:

```cpp
#define STR "ABC"
// ...
char s[] = STR;
puts(s);
s[2] = '!';
puts(s);
```

And I tried to modernize it with constexpr:

```cpp
constexpr char STR[] = "ABC"
// ...
char s[] = STR;
puts(s);
s[2] = '!';
puts(s);
```

But it no longer compiles.

How can I initialize a string on the stack from a constexpr constant without runtime penalty?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your "runtime penalty" requirement? Why do you have it? What problem does a "runtime penalty" give you? Have you tried to measure and benchmark and profile to learn that it's really a top-two (or possibly top-three) bottleneck in your system?

Comment: There's no problem and no bottleneck, I'm just trying to educate myself, and I'm asking how it's possible to do that in C++. I can as well use Python, but the question is about C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C-style arrays can only be initialized by literals, not by another array or `const char*`.

You can switch to `std::array`

```
constexpr std::array<char,4> STR{"ABC"};
int main() {
std::array s{STR};
// OR: auto s{STR};
}
```

Unfortunately, it requires specifying the length of the string literal in `STR`, if you have C++20, you can use [`std::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array):

```
constexpr std::array STR{std::to_array("ABC")};
```

optionally replacing `std::array` with `auto`.

If you do not have C++20, you can still use the implementation from the link above to write your own `to_array`.

There is also `std::string_view` and `std::span` but both are non-owning pointers.

Comment: That's cool. Actually, I was just able to do: `constexpr char STR[] = "ABC"` and then `auto s{std::to_array(ABC)};`.